# Orthorectification in QGIS

Tags: qgis, orthorectification

I'm a beginner in QGIS. I georeferenced 2 satellite photos and merged them, and now I want to orthorectify it but I don't know the steps in doing so.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. We are a problem-solving site, so Questions here are expected to contain a problem beyond basic howto research.  The standard follow-up questions here are "What have you tried?" and "What problem did you encounter?"  If you can't answer these, then you're probably not ready to ask a Question yet.